# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing when network use high

Tags: networking, wireless, freeze

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a brand new SSD hard drive. I had a previous ubuntu setup on a different hard drive but in the same desktop build (Same wifi adapter etc)

I had some issues with downloads failing halfway through then noticed the Ubuntu GUI was freezing too. These seem to link as the gui freezes as soon as the network use goes back to 0 after the peak and the download fails.

While the ubuntu GUI is frozen I can still navigate the web browser(Firefox) but any Ubuntu GUI like system monitor or switching windows is frozen.

Hardware Specs:

- Wireless card: Gigabyte GC-WB1733D-I Wireless-AC PCI-E Network Interface Card + Bluetooth v5.0-1733Mbps
- Processor: Intel BX80684I78700K 8th Gen Core i7-8700K Processor
- SSD: Crucial MX500 500 GB CT500MX500SSD1
- PSU: Corsair VS650 650 W Active PFC 80 PLUS Certified Power Supply Unit

Answer (score 0):

Ok so while writing the above question I had a thought that I had added the new SSD into my build without taking anything out (I have a few backup HDD's still in there). Unplugging these HDD's fixed the problem so I suspect it was a PSU issue.